# jquery datepicker in form tag

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I am building a webpage and I try to do this with HTML5. No I tried through cross-browsing to implement a datepicker...and yeaahh...it works. The problem now is, that the datepicker doesn't work, if I put my input-tag in my form. Here's my example:

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset="utf-8" />
            <title>My Page.</title>
            <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="blog.css" type="text/css">-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
            <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

            <script>
            $(function(){
                $("#datepicker").datepicker();
                });
            </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <form id="create_inserat" action="/inserat.php=<?php tbd ?>" method="post">
        <fieldset id="inserat">
            <legend>Inserat erfassen</legend>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <label for="start">Startdatum</label>
                    <input type="date" name="date" id="datepicker" value="" />
                </li>
            </ol>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    ....
```

What's wrong? Why does it work if I have the input-tag out of the form-tag, but in the form-tag (like my example) it doesn't work?

Hope, that someone can help me.

Greetings, Yab

Comment: can you make fiddle for it?

Comment: Are there two inputs with id="datepicker" in your HTML? jQuery will only select the first one, so if there's another one before the one in the form then it won't work. http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Answer (score -1):

The  element which attaches the datepicker functionality is above the form, so when it runs, it cannot find the datepicker input because it hasn't been created yet. You have two options.

- move the script to below the form
- run the script onload

EDIT: this is a load of rubbish as pointed out in the comments, although at least I learnt something from it.

The problem was in fact that there are two datepickers in the markup with the same ID, so jQuery will only find the first one with this construct:

```
 $("#datepicker")
```

The solution is simply to use a class of datepicker instead of an ID. The class selector in jQuery will match all elements with class="datepicker" and apply a datepicker to them.

```
 $(function(){
      $(".datepicker").datepicker();
 });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! Now it works for the first datepicker...the problem was, that it was an other datepicker befor the form-tag. I delete that datepicker. Now I have an other problem: I have two datepicker in my form. The first works perfectly, but the second one doesn't work. :-(